# Resigning as Mos Eisley room owner

Tags: discussion

Well, it'll always be Mos Eisley to me, seeing as I chatted there from 2012 to 2017. Old habits are hard to break!

I am resigning as Room Owner of the current SFF chatroom -- it's just not the same.

Let me take this opportunity to thank every user who stopped by, or became a regular user of, Mos Eisley. I, for one, value every conversation (for varying reasons, true) and cannot begin to count the number of intelligent, humorous, insightful, and kind users I met through chat -- I am grateful for our time together. I wish you all the very best :)

[image: *Psych* - Let's get some tacos!]

Comment: That's sad news but ofcourse it's your own choice and we should respect it. I hope you are not fully abandoning the chat.

Comment: I just wanted to share [this](https://68.media.tumblr.com/224898c9b10a8c335a997b847be651c1/tumblr_ntvooyBPLc1ucxz4zo1_500.gif).

Comment: I'm sad to see you step down; I hope you'll be around. _Godspeed you! Black Empress._

Comment: Awww :-( Sad news. I hope you'll still be around SFF chat even if not as a RO! Unlimited points to Slytherin :-)

Comment: I am grateful that I had the opportunity to meet you and chat with you in Mos Eisley.  I had the best time getting to know you and all of the other awesome people there who I now consider friends.  While it's sad that you're stepping down, I understand and respect your decision.  I agree, it's just not the same.  You will always be one of my favorite people!  Good luck, my dear :)

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I'm up-voting this because you've always seemed like a kind and good person, and I wish you luck in all future endeavors. I'm not up-voting because I'm glad to see you go. :)

Comment: @AlienWerepandaolf - No, I am not abandoning chat totally, but when one is a room owner there is kind of a compulsion to be in chat every day (at least I felt that way) to check in with users. I don't want to do that anymore. I'll be around, though :)

Comment: @Erik -- Thanks very much :) I really appreciate your kind words! I really enjoyed my time as a room owner, but it's time to move on to something new at SFF. Maybe I'll try editing :))