# What can we do to make our new primary chatroom as interesting as our old primary chatroom Mos Eisley?

Tags: discussion, chat

I remember sitting hours in front of Mos Eisley and I used to love chatting in it. And then, [Shog9 nuked it](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10914/how-come-our-main-chat-mos-eisley-got-frozen-this-time). Fine. Not a big deal. People are still same. This is what I thought.

But, no. I don't enjoy our new chatroom "The Restaurant at the End of the Universe". I can't sit here even for 5 minutes.

Other users are also experiencing the same: [Resigning as Mos Eisley room owner](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11086/resigning-as-mos-eisley-room-owner)

Why is it different? Why is the new chatroom boring? And, what can we do to make the situation better?

Comment: I'll caveat that whilst having a chat room be interesting is good, we shouldn't be aiming to make it specifically like Mos again. That it is different is the point.

Comment: The biggest difference between Mos and the Restaurant is that the people are *not* the same. Most of the former Mos regulars have more or less abandoned SE chat at this point, for a wide variety of reasons.

Comment: Quality is better then quantity and even if it's not that busy but at-least it's going fine with no drama.

Comment: OP is complaining about the new chatroom being "boring", so the "quality" does not seem to be there in his opinion.

Comment: When one of the most beloved users and RO's steps down, you know there is an issue. Admitting that issue is whole other ballgame.

Comment: @Skooba The RO stepped down because the room is "just not the same" -- that's a direct quote of their whole reason. Yes, it is not the same; that's the point. If it *was* the same it'd get shut down again. That there is an issue with the current room is something we can look at, but it can't be resolved with "go back to how Mos Eisley was".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61708/discussion-on-question-by-i-am-groot-what-can-we-do-to-make-our-new-primary-chat).

Comment: I left cuz of the offsite blues that came in and just flagged without context. Come moderate, but put in some effort and read the context first.

Comment: `Why is it different? Why is the new chatroom boring?` Why don't *you* start by telling us why you feel it's different and or boring?

Comment: @phantom42 maybe boring is better then the drama used to happen in old mos. I think we don't need to rush into anything and give TREU some time to grow.

Comment: @Skooba yeah that was the biggest lost I can see form the story but for now TREU don't even have much activity to need many ROs.

Comment: that's a valid concern - but that's not what OP seems to be looking for right now.

Comment: "The new chat room is boring and sucks!" *<this conversation has been moved to chat>*

Comment: I'm assuming we can't swear or crack real jokes anymore. So it should be nice and quiet (and empty but for lurkers) when I show up and ask random questions that I should just search Meta for. That sounds fun, right? Great, see you there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Do it yourself

I'll start off with this quote:

> *Be* the change you want to see in the world.
> <sub>-[Commonly attributed to Gandhi.](https://josephranseth.com/gandhi-didnt-say-be-the-change-you-want-to-see-in-the-world/)</sub>

Honestly, if you want to make TREU interesting, then all you have to do is: try it yourself. Make the place be the way that you want it to be.

The community is not here to make an interesting place *for you*, ready for you to pop-in and have an interesting discussion. *You* are also part of this community and are responsible for its success.

So the next time you pop-in and think "ahh, I wish there was a discussion about X", then go ahead and start that discussion.

### What even *is* the problem?

Why *do* you feel that it's "boring", not interesting and that you "don't enjoy it"? Rather than tell us a vague problem, and expect us to solve it for you, take a minute to analyse how or why you feel that way. [Talking it out loud to yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) can help you understand what the problem you're facing is.

### Effort, it takes effort

Having said that, I can tell you that to get a community going, it takes effort. Sometimes more, sometimes less. But trying is the only thing you can do.

This may be the reason that you might be finding TREU a "boring" place, people may just not want to or can't expend any effort there to get a discussion going.

At time of writing, [TREU has](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe):

- 87 posts per day
- 867 posts per week
- 93 all time users

[image: Image capture of the Chat Statistics page (linked above) for 'The Restaurant at the End of the Universe' chatroom. This shows that there have been 177 posts today, 95 yesterday and an average pf 87 posts per day. It also shows that there were 648 posts last week, 582 posts this week and an average of 867 posts per week. The statistic page also has links to 'join this room', 'view transcript' and a 'search [room] for messages containing' functionality. At the bottom of the image, we see that there have been 93 total users (all time) and nearly 14,000 posts (all time).]

That's not much, but it's not too bad either; it's kindling enough to get a good fire going, if stoked enough. So, the problem isn't necessarily the numbers, it's the amount of **engagement**, or lack thereof.

### In closing

Give it a go, try ([or don't try; *do*](http://whoisgarybledsoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/do_or_do_not_1920x1080_1923565073.jpg)). And if you find that it just isn't the place you want it to be, then move on, try something else.

Answer (score 13):

Something that I've noticed about the new room (and I was only in Mos for like a week before it hit the fan) is that it seems quieter. I think there are a few reasons for this:

- Old regulars got banned or left. This is unavoidable, there were things happening that should not be happening here.
- Old regulars who stuck around got scared. For a few days after Mos went down, basically anything referring to it was thrown in the Trash by a legion of mods. Which sort of makes sense, but made things difficult for everyone. I think we're at a point now where that's mostly cleared up, so it shouldn't be as much of an issue any more (and let us hope we never have to worry about it again).
- It's summer. On Worldbuilding at least, there's a dip in activity during the summertime. Not much can be done about this.

I'd say the main thing that should be done to make Restaurant a more interesting place is just for people to **step up and talk more**. I try not to because I tend to talk too much (I have the most posts by a wide margin on Factory Floor), and I don't feel like I've earned my place in the room yet, but as far as I know most people don't care about these things.

So if you're in the room, and waiting for someone else to speak up and entertain you, maybe it's just your turn to get the conversation started. Sometimes you'll be speaking to a void, but other times maybe you'll start something that people will come back for.

Comment: I agree we just need to talk more, and I think it'd be fine if we have people who tend to talk too much. That's preferable to not enough conversation. :)

Comment: There's no one to give you a place in the room. The only people who talk are mods and new users who never took part in the room before the shutdown. If you really want to keep talking in that room, *you* have to start the chat.

Comment: This was pretty much my exact attitude around a month ago. Since then I've gradually lost interest in "reviving" the Restaurant because 1) everyone I care about has already moved to the now-famous Slack chat, and 2) I finally admitted to myself that a complete loss of trust in the CMs and mods isn't something that will just stop being an issue if we have a high enough floof-to-drama ratio.

Comment: As we are constantly reminded, _most_ SE sites don't have a very active chat room and they truck along just fine. SF/F is merely joining their ranks. That's fine, it's a Q&A site, not a chat site. Most of us are content to focus on the Q&A and let the chat room die a slow and mostly un-remarked-upon death.

Comment: @KutuluMike Mos's death was not slow or un-remarked on, and as long as the Restaurant stays on good behavior it can be immortal! Boring, yes; but immortal none the less........

Comment: @KutuluMike: I don't think we should want to be typical.  The Blog, for example, was and is exceptional among SE sites.  What's important is that we be exceptional in good ways (again, the Blog) rather than bad ways (Mos Eisley).  Obviously mediocrity is better than outstanding badness, but I wouldn't call it a goal to strive for.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you're talking about.

I am a regular member of The Restaurant, and was a regular of Mos. And let me say that *I very much prefer The Restaurant.*

- It's not a hassle to keep from inappropriate discussion

  In Mos, the conversation was always turning to stuff not exactly SFW, or that everyone was comfortable with. The Restaurant doesn't have these problems. It's actually pleasant to sit in there now - most of the bad behavior is *gone*. And, from both a chatter and moderator viewpoint - *that's a good thing*.
- There *is* interesting stuff in The Restaurant

  While people are not always chatting - they weren't in Mos either - we do have some stuff including there, like the Daily Floof. And, personally, I find it much more pleasant and enjoyable to argue over what constitutes a proper floof than whether or not certain topics are acceptable for chat - and since the people who liked to discuss things like that are no longer in the chat, those kinds of conversations that sparked the arguments on what was acceptable for chat don't happen in The Restaurant.

I'm also going to see if I can get a chatbot somewhere ;)

Comment: I believe the first 6 iterations of the Daily Floof occurred in the *room that shall not be named*

Comment: Is the new chat room a "discuss SFF" room or "random chat" like Mos was?

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - both... like any good chatroom. But the inappropriate content that so often popped up in Mos is not present (and if found will be ejected).

Comment: @Mithrandir - Mos felt like 99% the latter.

Comment: I can't _imagine_ what you do in your free time if you find today's chat room interesting. No, sir.

Comment: @DVK An upside of the new room's deadness is that you can turn it into whatever you want (other than a hive of scum and villainy, of course). It'd only take 2 or 3 of us to fill it up with on-topic chatter and make that the new norm.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - I donno... i can imagine quite a bit </sw> :)

Comment: just a friendly head up, you may want to remove references to the slack channel... other users have been suspended (or at least chat suspended) for similar actions

Comment: So, I got a 6 month chat ban for mentioning it in chat, apparently.  It's serious enough for CMs to step on heads rather than follow the policy in place.